# AWS EC2 packet_write_wait: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Broken pipe

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After rebooting my instance I'm getting this error packet_write_wait: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Broken pipe.

I'm able to connect in other instances, moreover I have done all changes in ssh and sshd config files but none of them helps.